# How to set up a Drupal website with an accessible codebase in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a new local Drupal 7 website with Docker, using Docker Compose. I would like the *sites/all* and *sites/default/files* folders to be accessible via my file explorer, such that I can for example edit the files inside them in an editor and easily create custom modules.

**Document structure**

```
test-website
  --db-backups
  --sites
  --docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:7
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./sites:/var/www/html/sites
    restart: always

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./db-backups:/var/mysql/backups
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 3030:3030

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: user
      PMA_PASSWORD: password
      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
    ports:
     - 9090:9090

volumes:
  sites:
  db-backups:
```

Composing the *docker-compose.yml* file in the command line allows me to navigate to localhost:8080 as desired, but I get an error during the requirements verification step of the installation:

> The directory sites/default/files does not exist. An automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.

Something seems to be wrong with my volume, but I don't know what and I can't find clear documentation online. Also, I now tried to put *sites* as a whole in a volume, but that leads to data loss when the Docker containers are killed and restarted (see https://github.com/docker-library/drupal/issues/3). Thus, I need a solution that persists my data.

Which steps should I follow to set up my Drupal 7 website correctly?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I want to mount my sites/default/files so that it can be persistent on host. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **folder volumes** you don't need to define **docker volumes**

just remove your last 3 lines

```
volumes:
  sites:
  db-backups:
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this doesn't solve the problem about the missing *files* folder.